# Elasticsearch Query for not receiving data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

We are monitoring multiple servers with metricbeat. We want to create alert when metricbeat is stopped in any of the servers. If no data is receiving from that server from last 5 minute it means metricbeat is stopped in that server.

I want to know what can be the query for this alert.

```
PUT _watcher/watch/eba1f994-1306-4846-b586-5a2c6135b4bc
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "30m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "metricbeat-*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-5m",
                      "lte": "now"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "servers": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags",
                "size": 1000,
                "min_doc_count": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "array_compare": {
      "ctx.payload.aggregations.servers.buckets": {
        "path": "doc_count",
        "eq": {
          "value": 0,
          "quantifier": "some"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "my-logging-action": {
      "logging": {
        "level": "info",
        "text": "This servers are not sending data: {{#ctx.payload.aggregations.servers.buckets}} {{key}} {{doc_count}},{{/ctx.payload.aggregations.servers.buckets}}"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: are you going to create watcher or rules for alter ?

Comment: yes i want to create watcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use watcher configuration like below:

```json
PUT _watcher/watch/metric_check
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "indices": "your_index_name_or_index_pattern",
        "types": "count",
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-5m",
                      "lte": "now"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "servers": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "server_host_or_ip_field_name",
                "size": 100,
                "min_doc_count": 0
              },
              "aggs": {
                "the_filter": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "the_doc_count": "_count"
                    },
                    "script": "params.the_doc_count < 1"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "size": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
   "condition": {
      "array_compare": {
        "ctx.payload.aggregations.servers.buckets": {
          "path": "doc_count",
          "eq": {
             "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "actions": {
    "send_email": { 
      "email": {
        "to": "<username>@<domainname>", 
        "subject": "Watcher Notification - MetricBeat no data",
        "body": "This servers are not sending data: {{#ctx.payload.aggregations.servers.buckets}} {{key}},{{/ctx.payload.aggregations.servers.buckets}}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please [Array Comapre Condition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/condition-array-compare.html) and [Email Action](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/actions-email.html) documentation for more details..

**Note:** I have not validated configuration but it should work.

Comment: Thanks Sagar, we have installed metricbeat in two servers If for one server if service get stops then we should get alert from that server The script you have shared above it is for all servers who is sending logs but if metricbeat is stopped in any of the server then we should get alert

Comment: Hi Sagar, I will check this script and update you here

Comment: Hi Sagar i run your script but i am getting alert for all hosts . We are sending metricbeat data at 3 minute of interval and watcher script will run every 5 minute and it will check last 15 minute of data. But when i am running the script it is giving alert for all hosts

Comment: is index name and all configured correctly ? there should be some issue with query.

Comment: Hi Sagar I am getting result like this "This servers are not sending data:  xx.xx.xx.xx 20330, xx.xx.xx.xx 1397, xx.xx.xx.xx 1198, xx.xx.xx.xx 100,xx.xx.xx.xx 0. See for 0 doc_count it has to show "This servers are not sending data:  xx.xx.xx.xx 0

Comment: @aniketpant I have updated the script with aggregation. this should work for your case. You need to just trick the query and aggregation to get desire result.

Comment: Hi @Sagar Patel bro if i change size value from 100 to 1000 then it is capturing that particular host , so in future do i need to increase this value ?

Comment: @aniketpant how many server you are monitoring ?

Comment: 300 and in future we don't know

Comment: Ok.. then as of now you can go with 1k size because you need 0 count as well.